# mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars( $value )); is enough? how can i easly improve it?

Tags: php, mysql, security, sql-injection

i'm using this in every $_get or $_post before acces or insert to my Database..

i'm sure it's not enough.. but how safe is it? can i combine it with some expresion to make it safer?

thanks a lot!

so how about this? mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars( $value ));

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` has nothing to do with making it safe for database entry. Use the database's escape function or parameterized queries (PDO) for that.

Comment: your change of subject and body makes the answers look inadequate: looks like you've asked "should I do A" and the answers are "no, you should do A".  So I suggest that you revert your modifications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, that is not enough. You should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to prevent sql injection attacks.

Comment: @Toni, yeah, it looks better. I would however save the *raw* values (eg. without using `htmlspecialchars`). When you retrieve the values and show them on some page you can use `htmlspecialchars` to prevent XSS attacks, but there is no need to save the string encoded.

Comment: so is thre a way to make a function like if(string_not_dangerous($string)){ save_normal_sting;} else { show(go_to_hell)} ?

Comment: i was considering Dreamweaver Replace all open documents: htmlspecialchars -> mysql_real_escape_string,

Answer (score 0):

mysql_escape_string($value) is a bit smarter when sanitizing strings that will be used in an SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql_real_escape_string() to protect your database from injection attacks (or better yet, prepared statements with something like the PDO library) and htmlspecialchars() when you're *displaying* data pulled from a database.